# Drywall ceiling

Tags: drywall

First time drywall attempt here. The house I bought had an unfinished powder room that I'm trying to finish. Ceiling drywall was already present, but I noticed some patches were wobbly so I re-cut/re-mounted them. How did I do?

Also, is green lid AP joint compound good enough to pre-fill here? Or should I go buy something else?

Also, do I need to shave off the paper frayed edges with a utility knife? Or will mud take care of it?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Greenlid should do fine for your purposes here. Take the butt end of your trowel, or the smooth head of a hammer, and smoosh the ragged edges down, including those protruding screw hole divets. Those will rear their ugliness after a few coats.

Answer (score 0):

Use drywall tape for the seams. Joint compound the seams first then apply the tape. Smooth the tape out then joint compound over it with your spakle blade.  Good luck! Drywall repair and spakling takes time to perfect. 2nd coat or 3 coats are sometimes needed.